# Multiplying Matrices not giving right answer

Tags: c

I have written this basic code for my school class.  The code runs, but does not calculate the multiplied matrix correctly.  As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong, but that is why I am here.   It gives me numbers in the millions.
Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
 {
    for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
        c[i][j] = sum;
```

I think that this multiplication part is correct from what I have read elsewhere on these forums.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[10][10], c[10][10], i, j, k;
int sum = 0;
printf("Enter your values for the 2x4 matrix:\n");
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
}
int b[3][3];
b[0][0]=2;
b[1][0]=41;
b[2][0]=12;
b[3][0]=15;
b[0][1]=7;
b[0][2]=34;
b[0][3]=3;
b[1][1]=32;
b[2][1]=1;
b[3][1]=5;
b[1][2]=13;
b[1][3]=6;
b[2][2]=0;
b[3][2]=7;
b[2][3]=11;
b[3][3]=9;
 for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
        c[i][j] = sum;
    }
}
printf("Multiplication Of Two Matrices: \n");
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d ", c[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're violating your array boundaries in `b`, and as such invoking *undefined behavior*. `b` is declared as `int b[3][3]`. The first element is `b[0][0]`, the last is `b[2][2]`. Everything with a `3` or larger in *either* subscript position is wrong.

Comment: size of matrix `b` is `int b[3][3];` you cannot perform `b[0][3]=3;`, `b[1][3]=6;`, `b[2][3]=11;` and `b[3][3]=9;` As size is 3x3 you can access index 0,1, and 2.

Comment: Matrix A is 4*2. You need matrix B to be 2*n to multiply. Then the resultant matrix will be of size 4*n

Comment: `int b[4][4] = { {2,41,12,15}, {7,34,3,32}, {1,5,13,6}, {0,7,11,9} };` will create the array and fill in the values. Note that I didn't try to put the numbers in the right places (the order in which you filled in the array is very strange, indeed).

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes:

- Your mistake is in the definition of the `b` matrice. it is of size 3x3 but your definition makes it of 4x4. To be clear, `b` begins from `b[0][0]` and ends at `b[2][2]`, thus having `3x3=9` elements.
- Matrix `a` is of size 4x2. matrix `b` is of size 3x3. the two cannot be multiplied. either matrix `b` should be changed to 2x3 size or `a` to 4x3 size.

So, the correct code will be:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int a[10][10], c[10][10], i, j, k;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter your values for the 2x4 matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int b[3][3];
    b[0][0]=2;
    b[1][0]=41;
    b[2][0]=12;
   /* b[3][0]=15; */
    b[0][1]=7;
    b[0][2]=34;
    b[0][3]=3;
    b[1][1]=32;
    b[2][1]=1;
   /* b[3][1]=5; */
    b[1][2]=13;
    b[1][3]=6;
    b[2][2]=0;
    b[3][2]=7;
    b[2][3]=11;
  /*  b[3][3]=9; */
     for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++)
            {
                sum = sum + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
            c[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    printf("Multiplication Of Two Matrices: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
    }
```